# parseFloat returning NAN even tough I am parsing a number

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

Problem using parseFloat even though I am parsing a number, but still returing NaN

```
<div class="tip-custom" id="tip-custom"><input type="number" placeholder="CUSTOM"></div>

const tipCustom = document.querySelector(".tip-custom");
tipCustom.addEventListener("input", tipInputFun);
let tipValue = 0.15;
 function tipInputFun() {
  tipValue = parseFloat(tipCustom.value / 100);
  console.log(tipValue);
}
```

Comment: `tipCustom` is the div, not the input.

Answer (score 2):

Your `querySelector` looks for an element that has a class `tip-custom`.

In your code I see a `div` with **id** tip-custom (that is `#tip-custom`) and your input being inside the div.

You need to fix your selector to properly find the element with your text. You could do something like this

```js
document.querySelector("#tip-custom>input");
```

Takes the first input, inside an element with id tip-custom.

```js
const tipCustom = document.querySelector("#tip-custom>input");

tipCustom.addEventListener("input", tipInputFun);
let tipValue = 0.15;

function tipInputFun() {
  tipValue = parseFloat(tipCustom.value / 100);
  console.log(tipValue);
}
```

```html
<div class="tip-custom" id="tip-custom"><input type="number" placeholder="CUSTOM"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`tipCustom` is the div, not the input, so `tipCustom.value` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and follow the good practices.

```js
let tipValue = 0.15;
function tipInput() {
  tipValue = parseFloat(this.value / 100);
  console.log(tipValue);
}
document.querySelector(".tip-custom > input").addEventListener("input", tipInput);
```

```html
<div class="tip-custom" id="tip-custom"><input type="number" placeholder="CUSTOM"></div>
```